# Suicide in the Kitchen (or murder...)

Tags: mystery

One day a detective investigates a case where a dead man was found in the kitchen of his house. Police reason that this was an act of suicide, judging that he had pills in his mouth. The detective opens the refrigerator and finds some lettuce, a chopped tomato, a marinating steak, a slice of cheddar cheese, and a half-drunken water bottle. The detective was like "Of course this is a murder!"

What was the detective's reasoning?

Comment: Did he die because of the pills? it says they were in his mouth, not swallowed.

Comment: @Areeb a lil' switcheroo...

Comment: he **ate** them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe

> he saw the steak and realized that the man was planning to cook it?

Comment: ... especially because it was marinating

Comment: I kinda hope this isn't the answer. I mean, perhaps he has a partner who was marinating the steak. Or perhaps his mental state suddenly changed (because of bad news, or just because brains are weird things) between putting the steak in to marinate and killing himself.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan yeah it seems entirely too simple to be such an answer, even though everything in the fridge points to him cooking something

Comment: Just as I comment too, well I guess this is the answer

Comment: Or it could have been an accidental overdose, not murder.

Answer (score 1):

The detective saw the bloody knife, or smoking gun, or other evidence of murder not in the list of food.

Comment: no, he did not...